# fastText producing zero vector

Tags: python, spatial, word-embedding, fasttext

I am facing the following error which calculating the cosine similarity on embeddings produced by fastText:

```
/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/CiteKP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py:721: RuntimeWarn
ing: invalid value encountered in float_scalars                                                          
  dist = 1.0 - uv / np.sqrt(uu * vv)
```

Relevant code snippets:

```
# fastText supervised training:
model = fasttext.train_supervised('merged_data_labels_prepended.txt')
model.save_model('fasttext_supervised.bin')

# model loading
model = fasttext.load_model("fasttext_supervised.bin")
```

```
# calculating cosine similarity
from scipy import spatial
def cosine_distance_wordembedding_method(s1, s2):
    vec1   = np.mean([model[word] for word in s1],axis=0)
    vec2   = np.mean([model[word] for word in s2],axis=0)
    cosine = spatial.distance.cosine(vec1, vec2)
    return round((1-cosine)*100, 2)

cosine_distance_wordembedding_method(pred.split(), label.split()) # function call
```

Initial Analysis:

fastText is producing all zeros embeddings (either vec1 or vec2 is zero sometimes) for words not in the vocabulary. So, how can I handle these OOV words to get non-zero embeddings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, setting `maxn=6` fixed the problem. By default, it is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Might the words for which you are receiving origin vectors (all `0.0` dimensions) be very short - shorter than the `min_n` parameter used when the model was constructed?

If so, that's what the model is designed to do. FastText can only synthesize vectors for OOV words when the candidate word has substrings that may have received n-gram-vectors during earlier training.

If the training only created these word-fragment vectors for character-n-grams of 3 characters or more, and you ask FastText for to make a vector for an OOV 2-character word, it has neither a full-word vector, nor subword vectors, to combine to the OOV vector. So it returns the zero-vector.

The best you can do in such a situation is detect the situation before assuming the vector is non-zero - & probably then just ignore that unknown word, with its unguessable vector, entirely.

Comment: `minn` parameter is `0` in my case. So, I believe that I don't get OOV because of that but maybe because the model doesnt encounter that n-gram before. BTW, what's the unguessable vector?

Comment: To give an example, the training has the word `__label__AET_HUM` in the file but still the model produces zero embeddings for the word `AET_HUM`.

Comment: What's the `maxn` parameter? (Are you sure your model is training/tracking *any* character n-grams, which is would have to do to be able to generate OOV vectors?) By "unguessable vector", I mean the vector for a word that FastText can't "guess (using substrings). For example, with a typical configuration of `minn=3`, `maxn=5`, if you were to supply a OOV word `'zz'`, and that wasn't in the training data, it will – by design - return a zero-vector, because there's no basis fo guessing (no 3-, 4-, or 5- character substrings).

Comment: Apparently, `maxn` parameter fixed the problem. By default, it is `0`. Changing it to `maxn=6` fixed the problem. But I am not sure why the default parameter 0 worked at all for encoding any string. Documentation says "maxn->max length of char ngram".

Comment: Great! FWIW, I think you're allowed to have both `minn` & `maxn` at `0`, which means: no subword info – similar to `bucket=0`. (If you've increased `maxn`, you should probably increase `minn`, also, & for anything like natural language, to at least `3` – because 1 or 2 char substrings are probably noise.)